# Update statement involving two different catalogs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

Trying to execute an update of a single field where the current db wants to pull values from last night's backup. Should be something close to:

```
update myTable 
   set status = (select status 
                   from .lastBackup.dbo.myTable as t 
                  where t.idField = idField)
```

Help?

Comment: Structure of the table/s in question and sample data would would help.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about a "normal" SQL backup, then no, that catalog isn't accessable via TSQL without doing a full restore. If that "backup" already exists as another database on the same server, then Joe's syntax is correct.

Comment: structure would be implied as identical by reference to 'last night's backup' figured more would have just gotten in the way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
update t
    set status = b.status
    from myTable t
        inner join lastBackup.dbo.myTable b
            on t.idField = b.idField
```

Comment: @OMG: I think that's a first. Do I earn a badge for that? :-)

Comment: @justSteve: I'll take an "accepted answer" in place of that beer for now. :-)